# Unique IVs producing identical ciphertext using attr_encrypted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, attr-encrypted

Using the most basic setup:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_encrypted :name, 
                 key: 'This is a key that is 256 bits!!', 
                 encode: true, 
                 encode_iv: true, 
                 encode_salt: true
end
```

The results look like this in the database when supplying an identical name:

```
╔════╦══════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ id ║ encrypted_name               ║ encrypted_name_iv ║
╠════╬══════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 1  ║ aVXZb1b317nroumXVBdV9pGxA2o= ║ JyE7wHups+3upY5e  ║
║ 2  ║ aVXZb1b317nroumXVBdV9pGxA2o= ║ uz/ktrtbUAksg5Vp  ║
╚════╩══════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Why is the ciphertext identical? Isn't that the part of the point of iv, which the gem is using by default?

Comment: It looks like the iv is not being used. What are the default options for `attr_encrypted`, do they include `encode_iv: true`?

Comment: @zaph - agreed, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you give us exact versions of the `attr_encrypted` and `encrytor` gems that you have installed?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this with a blank application using Rails 4.2.3, attr_encrypted 2.0.0, and encryptor 2.0.0. I'm starting to suspect a bug in the gem, but I haven't had time to crack it open... @BoraMa

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:** *the following is the original post explaining the whole problem, the issue is fixed now, see the bottom of this answer for a solution.*

I am quite sure you **noticed a rather nasty security issue** in the [`encryptor` gem](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/encryptor) (the gem that is used by `attr_encrypted` to do the actual encryptions).

The problem is that when using the `aes-256-gcm` algorithm (or any of the `AES GCM` algorithms), the **initialization vector (IV) is currently indeed not taken into account** when encrypting. The issue does not affect other algorithms but unfortunately the `aes-256-gcm` is the default algorithm in `attr_encrypted`.

As it turns out, **[it is the order of setting the IV vs. the encryption key](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#class-OpenSSL::Cipher-label-Authenticated+Encryption+and+Associated+Data+-28AEAD-29)** what causes the issue. When IV is set *before* the key (as [is in the gem](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/encryptor/blob/master/lib/encryptor.rb#L63)), the IV is not taken into account but it is if set *after* the key.

**Some tests to prove the problem:**

While taking parts of the `encryptor` gem code, I created the simplest test case to prove the problem (tested under ruby 2.3.0 compiled against OpenSSL version "1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014"):

```
def base64_enc(bytes)
  [bytes].pack("m")
end

def test_aes_encr(n, cipher, data, key, iv, iv_before_key = true)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new(cipher)
  cipher.encrypt

  # THIS IS THE KEY PART OF THE ISSUE
  if iv_before_key
    # this is how it's currently present in the encryptor gem code
    cipher.iv = iv
    cipher.key = key
  else
    # this is the version that actually works
    cipher.key = key
    cipher.iv = iv
  end

  if cipher.name.downcase.end_with?("gcm")
    cipher.auth_data = ""
  end

  result = cipher.update(data)
  result << cipher.final

  puts "#{n} #{cipher.name}, iv #{iv_before_key ? "BEFORE" : "AFTER "} key: " +
           "iv=#{iv}, result=#{base64_enc(result)}"
end

def test_encryption
  data = "something private"
  key = "This is a key that is 256 bits!!"

  # control tests using AES-256-CBC
  test_aes_encr(1, "aes-256-cbc", data, key, "aaaabbbbccccdddd", true)
  test_aes_encr(2, "aes-256-cbc", data, key, "eeeeffffgggghhhh", true)
  test_aes_encr(3, "aes-256-cbc", data, key, "aaaabbbbccccdddd", false)
  test_aes_encr(4, "aes-256-cbc", data, key, "eeeeffffgggghhhh", false)

  # failing tests using AES-256-GCM
  test_aes_encr(5, "aes-256-gcm", data, key, "aaaabbbbcccc", true)
  test_aes_encr(6, "aes-256-gcm", data, key, "eeeeffffgggg", true)
  test_aes_encr(7, "aes-256-gcm", data, key, "aaaabbbbcccc", false)
  test_aes_encr(8, "aes-256-gcm", data, key, "eeeeffffgggg", false)
end
```

Running `test_encryption` which encrypts a text using `AES-256-CBC` and then using `AES-256-GCM`, each time with two different IVs in two regimes (IV set before/after key), gets us the following results:

```
# control tests with CBC:
1 AES-256-CBC, iv BEFORE key: iv=aaaabbbbccccdddd, result=4IAGcazRmEUIRDE3ZpEgoS0Nmm1/+nrd5VT2/Xab0WM=
2 AES-256-CBC, iv BEFORE key: iv=eeeeffffgggghhhh, result=T7um2Wgb2vw1r4uryF3xnBeq+KozuetjKGItfNKurGE=
3 AES-256-CBC, iv AFTER  key: iv=aaaabbbbccccdddd, result=4IAGcazRmEUIRDE3ZpEgoS0Nmm1/+nrd5VT2/Xab0WM=
4 AES-256-CBC, iv AFTER  key: iv=eeeeffffgggghhhh, result=T7um2Wgb2vw1r4uryF3xnBeq+KozuetjKGItfNKurGE=

# the problematic tests with GCM:
5 id-aes256-GCM, iv BEFORE key: iv=aaaabbbbcccc, result=Tl/HfkWpwoByeYRz6Mz4yIo=
6 id-aes256-GCM, iv BEFORE key: iv=eeeeffffgggg, result=Tl/HfkWpwoByeYRz6Mz4yIo=
7 id-aes256-GCM, iv AFTER  key: iv=aaaabbbbcccc, result=+4Iyn7RSDKimTQi0S3gn58E=
8 id-aes256-GCM, iv AFTER  key: iv=eeeeffffgggg, result=3m9uEDyb9eh1RD3CuOCmc50=
```

These tests show that while the order of setting IV vs. key is not relevant for CBC, [it is for GCM](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#class-OpenSSL::Cipher-label-Authenticated+Encryption+and+Associated+Data+-28AEAD-29). More importantly, the encrypted result in CBC is different for two different IVs, whereas it is not for GCM if IV set before the key.

I just created a [pull request](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/encryptor/pull/22) to fix this issue in the `encryptor` gem. Practically, you have a few options now:

- Wait till a new version of the `encryptor` gem is released.
- Use also salt with `attr_encrypted`. You should use salt anyway to further secure the encrypted data.

The very unfortunate thing is that all already encrypted data will become undecipherable after the fix as suddenly the IVs will be taken into account.

### Update: `encryptor` 3.0.0 available

You can now [upgrade the `encryptor` gem to version 3.0](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/encryptor#upgrading-from-v200-to-v300) in which the bug is fixed. Now, if this is the first time you use the `encryptor` or `attr_encrypted` gems you are all set and everything should work correctly.

If you have data that is already encrypted using `encryptor` 2.0.0, then **you must manually re-encrypt** the data after the gem upgrade, otherwise it will fail to decrypt correctly! You will be warned about this during the gem upgrade. The schematic procedure is as follows:

- You have to decrypt all your encrypted data using the `Encryptor` class (see the [README](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/encryptor#basic) for examples), using the `:v2_gcm_iv => true` option. This should correctly decrypt your data.
- Then you must encrypt the same data back again, now without this option (i.e. `:v2_gcm_iv => false`) but including the proper IV from your database.
- If you have production data, you will need to do this upgrade offline and immediately after the gem update to ensure no data corruption.

### Update 2: issue in the `openssl` gem confirmed and fixed

FYI, it was recently [confirmed](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/issues/49#issuecomment-248171371) that this had actually been an **issue in the underlying ruby-openssl library** and **the bug has been [fixed](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/issues/49#issuecomment-250094459) now**. So, in the future, it is possible that even `attr_encrypted` gem version 2.x will actually work correctly when used with the new `openssl-2.0.0` gem version (which is now in beta as of Sep 2016).

Comment: Wow - great effort! I hadn't even considered that "The very unfortunate thing is that all already encrypted data will become undecipherable after the fix as suddenly the IVs will be taken into account.", but I suspect that you are correct... Nice work on this answer!

Answer (score 0):

If the plain text, key and IV are the same the encrypted text will be the same.

It looks like you need to use:

```
attr_encrypted :email, key: 'some secret key', encode: true, encode_iv: true, encode_salt: true
```

Note: `encode_iv: true`

Or perhaps set the default option `encode_iv: true`

Documentation: [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted)

Comment: sure, that makes sense, but it seems the gem is generating a random IV for each encryption by default

Comment: I have tried using encode: true, and the result is the same.